# Sort lines by group and column

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

I have a csv file separated by semicolons. Which contains lines as shown below.. And I need to sort it by the first and third column, respecting the groups of lines defined by the value of the first column.

```
booke;book;2
booke;booke;1
booke;bookede;6
booke;bookedes;8
booke;booker;4
booke;bookes;7
booke;booket;3
booking;booking;1
booking;bookingen;2
booking;bookingens;3
booking;bookinger;7
booking;bookingerne;5
booking;bookingernes;6
booking;bookingers;8
booking;bookings;4
```

Expected output:

```
booke;booke;1
booke;book;2
booke;booket;3
booke;booker;4
booke;bookede;6
booke;bookes;7
booke;bookedes;8
booking;booking;1
booking;bookingen;2
booking;bookingens;3
booking;bookings;4
booking;bookingerne;5
booking;bookingernes;6
booking;bookinger;7
booking;bookingers;8
```

I tried it with `sort -t; -k3,3n -k1,1` but it's sorted by the third entire column.

Comment: Switch `-k3,3n` and `-k1,1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using two sorts in a pipeline fashion:

```
sort -t ';' -k 3,3n | sort -t ';' -k 1,1 -s
```

The `-s` in the second parameter is necessary in order to enable *stable sort*. Otherwise it could destroy the previous (third column) sorting.

**EDIT**: however as @BenjaminW. points out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581530/sort-lines-by-group-and-column/34581584#comment56908246_34581530), you can use multiple `-k` flags, you only specified them the wrong way. By performing a sort:

```
sort -t ';' -k 1,1 -k 3,3n
```

It takes the first column als primary sorting column and the third as secondary.